# Can't update from php 5.5.12 - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to update php. When I check my php version, it returns:

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: Mar 10 2017 16:27:17) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

So I added ondrej's repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

But STILL:

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: Mar 10 2017 16:27:17) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

I don't know what to do anymore... Already tried purge, everything... this php doesn't upgrade, it remains this version. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you type php7.0 -v instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem while upgrading from PHP5 to PHP7 on Ubuntu 16.04

with Apache, here's what helped me (credit goes here):

Disable PHP5 module on Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
```

Now enable PHP7:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

To reflect changes Apache restart is required:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

By the way run `phpinfo()` in your script take a look which version is this running. Command line php is a complete separate system

Comment: well, I'm new to this... I was trying to update in order to get Composer, which is asking me for Open SSL that I wasn't being able to get... 

whatever. 

When I tried to disable PHP5:

    `ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!`

and I thought I wouldn't need apache, so... I'm really lost. (I had apache2, tried to remove it, not sure if it worked)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run First :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then : For PHP 5.5, PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

You have flipped "apt" and "add". Please take a look at your command.

Then the other steps that you made.

Comment: oh, I copied that from some website/forum. Anyway, I flipped the way you said, and nothing changed :(

Comment: ok try then to delete all php versions you have : "sudo apt-get purge php*"             and then "sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0"

Comment: same... php 5.5.12 remains. seems like apache2 has something to do with it and I can't change it